# Operator in Denominator

Tags: analysis, operator-theory

So I chanced upon this statement, and I'm not sure what is happening:
$$
\left(c-\frac{1}{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right)^{-1}e^{-ax/b}=\left(c-\frac{a(a-1)}{b^2}\right)^{-1}e^{-ax/b}.
$$
What I tried was was this:
$$
\left(c-\frac{1}{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right)^{-1}e^{-ax/b}=\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right)e^{ax/b}\right)^{-1}=\left(\left(c-\frac{1}{b}\frac{a}{b}-\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right)e^{ax/b}\right)^{-1}=\left(\left(c-\frac{a(a+1)}{b^2}\right)e^{ax/b}\right)^{-1}=\left(c-\frac{a(a+1)}{b^2}\right)^{-1}e^{-ax/b}.
$$

But the sign in the $a$ polynomial is different. Is there some trickery involved when operators are in the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument uses
$$
A^{-1} e^{-ax/b} = (Ae^{ax/b})^{-1}  
$$
but
$$
(Ae^{ax/b})^{-1} = e^{-ax/b} A^{-1}
$$
which is different.

I am not sure, but
$$
A^{-1} e^{-ax/b} = f \iff e^{-ax/b} = A f
$$
where the last one is a differential equation. The solution $f$ is probably the RHS given.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you figured out this issue already since the question is a few months old but for the sake of completeness.

Functions of operators are defined in terms of their power expansion. Thus in this case since the operand $e^{-ax/b}$ is an eigenfunction of the operand $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, you can just replace the operator by the eigenvalue $-a/b$ to get the desired result.

For an arbitrary operand you just need to decompose it into eigenvectors to study the operation of the operator function.